# How to Merge rows in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

In MySQL I want to merge information into a single row where we have the following scenario:

**Data**

```
uid |date       |cl      |m      |

149 |2017-03-19 |NULL    |14.2857|
149 |2017-03-19 |46.1538 |NULL   |
```

In above table I have information for the same **uid** and **date** and I want to merge them into a single row as given below.

**Merged Information**

```
uid |date       |cl      |m      |

149 |2017-03-19 |46.1538 |14.2857|
```

Comment: You can achieve  this using  GROUP BY uid

Comment: What happens if `cl` and `m` are not null in both rows ?

Comment: try `select max(columnname) from table group by uid`

Comment: @Vatev It will be '0' in case of NULL

Comment: This process is called pivot..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following :

```
SELECT      t.uid,
            t.date,
            MAX(t.cl) AS cl,
            MAX(t.m) AS m
FROM        TableName t
GROUP BY    t.date,
            t.uid
```

You can see this here -> http://rextester.com/OROY60007

**EDIT** : If you want to represent `NULL` as 0, you can make use of the `ISNULL` function in SQL. This will lead to a very minor change in the current query :

```
SELECT      t.uid,
            t.date,
            ISNULL(MAX(t.cl), 0) AS cl,
            ISNULL(MAX(t.m), 0) AS m
FROM        TableName t
GROUP BY    t.date,
            t.uid
```

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: [date] is MSSQL syntax for allowing a reserved word in MySQL you need to use backticks

Comment: I think I should convert null into 0, before running this code right?

Comment: You can use COALESCE(yourrow, 0) which will return 0 if yourrow is NULL (the value of yourrow otherwise)

Comment: @PeterGrundmann You're right. However, I'd suggest using the `ISNULL` method due to clarity of intention.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `GROUP BY`.

Assuming your date is unique as well as your uid then:

```
SELECT uid, date, MAX(cl) AS cl, MAX(m) AS m
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY uid, date
```

If not then:

```
SELECT uid, MAX(date), MAX(cl) AS cl, MAX(m) AS m
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY uid
```

Adjust `MIN`/`MAX` to suite your output needs.

Comment: MIN and MAX are the same in this instance!

Comment: @Strawberry depends on their data, the small sample they provided I assume isn't ALL their data.